# MIME ParseMediaType fails on multipart boundary

Tags: http, go, mime-types

I am a Golang api that accept multipart/form-data requests. For some clients, however, it fails to parse the form because it doesn't like the boundary being used by the client.

The header from the client is:

```
Content-Type:[multipart/form-data; boundary================1648430772==]
```

I've narrowed this down to the `ParseMediaType` function in the `mime` package.

If I call:

```
bad := "multipart/form-data; boundary=1650458473"
d, params, err := mime.ParseMediaType(v)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("err", err)
}
fmt.Println(d, params)
```

I get the err: `mime: invalid media parameter`.

Note that if I do this call with

```
multipart/form-data; boundary=3fc88aad6d1341a4921fd5ac9efe607c
```

it succeeds no problem.

According to the https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html spec, it looks to me like these are all valid characters for a boundary.

Is this a bug in the Go mime library? Or is this really an invalid boundary?

Comment: Can you show exactly what the request looks like? Both your examples can work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rfc you linked to contains BNF for the boundary and multipart body, it does not contain the BNF for the [Content-Type Header Field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521#section-4). So while `=` in boundary is just fine it's not fine in the `parameter` `value` of the `Content-Type` header. At least not unquoted.

So to fix your first example change the Content-Type to this:

`multipart/form-data; boundary="===============1648430772=="`

https://play.golang.org/p/3Iuk_ACZaQ

Your second example `multipart/form-data; boundary=1650458473` seems to work fine.

https://play.golang.org/p/xJWwBa_QiP

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer. In the RFC 2045 doc (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) it states that certain values cannot be used as parameter values in the `Content-Type` header.

The pertinent section:

```
     tspecials :=  "(" / ")" / "<" / ">" / "@" /
               "," / ";" / ":" / "\" / <">
               "/" / "[" / "]" / "?" / "="
               ; Must be in quoted-string,
               ; to use within parameter values
```

So you can use an equal sign, but only if it's quoted, so Go fails on the parsing. The client in this case is sending a technically-incorrect value for the `boundary` param.